# Regex custom replace function in C

Tags: c, string, replace, substring, pcre

i have been modifying this code https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/program.php?test=regexredux&lang=gcc&id=3 to make a pcre replace function.

At the moment I'm trying to give it the option to replace multiples consecutive occurrences with the 1st one and have this code (see comment in middle)

```
static char * fb_subst_updating(fbuf_t * dst, char * src,
    const char * p,
        const char * r) {
    pcre * re;
    pcre_extra * re_ex;
    const char * re_e;
    char * dp;
    int index_last_coincidence = -1;
    int re_eo, m[3], pos, rlen, clen, coincidence_length;
    if (!(re = pcre_compile(p, 0, & re_e, & re_eo, NULL)))
        exit(1);
    re_ex = pcre_study(re, PCRE_STUDY_JIT_COMPILE, & re_e);
    // The for loop iterates though all the coincidences matches.
    for (dst - > len = 0, rlen = strlen(r), pos = 0; pcre_exec(re, re_ex, src, strlen(src), pos, 0, m, 3) >= 0; pos = m[1]) {
        //m[0] and m[1] are the first and second index position 
        //of the coincidence in the iteration
        clen = m[0] - pos;
        if (r[0] == '$') { 

            coincidence_length = m[1] - m[0];
            dp = fb_need(dst, clen + coincidence_length);
            dst - > len += clen + coincidence_length;
            char coincidence_value[coincidence_length];
            memcpy(coincidence_value, & src[m[0]], coincidence_length);
            memcpy(dp, src + pos, clen);
            if (index_last_coincidence == m[0]) {
                index_last_coincidence = m[1];

                // I'm sure that my problem is here
                // This line could be ignored according to my logic,
                // but the result is the same:
                memcpy(dp + clen, coincidence_value, 0);
            } else {
                index_last_coincidence = m[1];
                memcpy(dp + clen, coincidence_value, coincidence_length);
            }
        } else {
            dp = fb_need(dst, clen + rlen);
            dst - > len += clen + rlen;
            memcpy(dp, src + pos, clen);
            memcpy(dp + clen, r, rlen);
        }
    }
    clen = strlen(src) - pos;
    dp = fb_need(dst, clen);
    dst - > len += clen;
    memcpy(dp, src + pos, clen);
    return dst - > buf;
}
```

I have this text input:

> RT @pacobazan_: Me encanta como se revientan cañones entre ellos.  (@LibreriaSur)Muy eeeeeeee de República Burgués con statichipocresía social, donde todo funciona por autobombo, palmadita al amigo y argolla. (@LibreriaSur)(@LibreriaSur)(@LibreriaSur)Argolla en el cine, argolla en el periodismo, argolla en la tv. Grupitos de amigos (@LibreriaSur)jugando a ser talentosos. RT @MijaelGLP : Unas chelas para celebrar la inauguración de la (@LibreriaSur)esquina de libros de (@LibreriaSur) en Café Julieta con dos maestros:…

The pattern is this:

> ((@[A-Za-z0-9_]+))

the replace is: `$1`

and the result that I'm getting atm is:

> RT @pacobazan_: Me encanta como se revientan cañones entre ellos.  (@LibreriaSur)Muy eeeeeeee de República Burgués con statichipocresía social, donde todo funciona por autobombo, palmadita al amigo y argolla. (@LibreriaSur)

and it should replace `(@LibreriaSur)(@LibreriaSur)(@LibreriaSur)` with `(@LibreriaSur)`

It don't continue copying after the first consecutive coincidence and haven't figure out what could be.

According my logic it should not copy if the initial position of previous coincidence is the same as the final position of the actual coincidence and continue with the rest in the next iteration.

It works fine if there is no consecutive coincidences or if i use a normal replace.

I'm almost sure that is a silly error but i have just a couple of days using C and can't figure it out. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: _"It stops after the first consecutive coincidence and haven't figure out what could be."_ Sounds like a good time to learn how to use a debugger to step through code and check values of variables along the way. Please also see my edit for how to use markdown correctly and ensure line breaks actually work.

Comment: I'm trying to run the code in a separate environment at the moment but im still configuring it. Im running this code with CGO in golang and cant debugge it easily atm. It does not stop, maybe i used the wrong word, it just don't copy more.

Comment: Did you intentionally use html tags to format the appearance of your question, or are those part of the input and the desired output? If you want the tags to be visible (instead of applied) in your question, then use the button `{}` after selecting the part of your question which should appear as literal code quote.

Comment: Note the edit by @underscore_d, which I think implies the same question as mine.

Comment: You'll get more/better answers if you provide a minimum example. As is, your question has a massive code dump and you are asking us to wade through it. Instead, distill it down to just a few lines that are not behaving in the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the edit already checked it out. Will have that in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i finally figured a way to make it work, had to refactor all the function using temporal variables, strcat, strcpy and concatenating with '\0'. Here is the result:

```
static char * replace2(char * text,
const char * pattern,
    const char * replace_value) {
char * result;
result = (char * ) malloc(8192);
pcre * re;
pcre_extra * re_ex;
const char * re_e;
int len_text = strnlen(text, strlen(text)), index_last_coincidencia = -1;
char * dp;
int re_eo, m[3], pos, rlen, clen;
if (!(re = pcre_compile(pattern, 0, & re_e, & re_eo, NULL))) exit(1);
re_ex = pcre_study(re, PCRE_STUDY_JIT_COMPILE, & re_e);
for (rlen = strnlen(replace_value, strlen(replace_value)), pos = 0; pcre_exec(re, re_ex, text, len_text, pos, 0, m, 3) >= 0; pos = m[1]) {

    if (replace_value[0] == '$') {
        if (index_last_coincidencia == m[0]) {
            index_last_coincidencia = m[1];
        } else {
            index_last_coincidencia = m[1];
            char * tmp;
            tmp = (char * ) malloc(m[0] - pos);
            strncpy(tmp, & text[pos], m[0] - pos);
            tmp[m[0] - pos] = '\0';
            strcat(result, tmp);
            free(tmp);
            tmp = (char * ) malloc(m[1] - m[0]);
            strncpy(tmp, & text[m[0]], m[1] - m[0]);
            tmp[m[1] - m[0]] = '\0';
            strcat(result, tmp);
            free(tmp);
        }
    } else {
        char * tmp;
        tmp = (char * ) malloc(m[0] - pos);
        strncpy(tmp, & text[pos], m[0] - pos);
        tmp[m[0] - pos] = '\0';
        strcat(result, tmp);
        free(tmp);
        tmp = (char * ) malloc(rlen);
        strncpy(tmp, replace_value, rlen);
        tmp[rlen] = '\0';
        strcat(result, tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
char * tmp;
int size = (strnlen(text, strlen(text)) - pos);
tmp = (char * ) malloc(size);
strncpy(tmp, & text[pos], size);
tmp[size] = '\0';
strcat(result, tmp);
free(tmp);
return result;}
```